# Problems with npm not respecting npm-shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap

I've recently been given responsibility of an old Nodejs app that's on node 8.9.4. The app has a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file with specific versions defined for its direct and indirect dependencies.

However, when I do a fresh npm install (using npm version 6.0.1, which is what previous developers had specified in the build job), it looks like `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is being ignored and whatever is specified in the `package.json` of the dependencies (in some cases 'latest') is the version that's being installed. The app doesn't have a `package-lock.json` file.

Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Not directly what you're asking but in scope of clean installation, you could check up `npm ci` command which is more strict than `npm install`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci and maybe it will work better for you

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Would I need to do anything special with the shirnkwrap file or would it just work?

Comment: From what I see in the docs, it should just work